# Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTE, can't do backup using deja-dup.

Tags: backup, deja-dup

When scheduled backup starts, I get following message:

```
Computer name changed the existing backup is of a computer named seth-ga-b85m-ds3h-a, but the current computer's name is unallocated.barefruit.co.uk. If this is unexpected you should back up to a different location
```

The name I assigned the computer is `seth-ga-...` When I check the computer name using the System Settings app, that name is still displayed after the error message. My designated backup location is on a USB hard drive named Backup Data. When the problem first occurred a couple weeks ago, I clicked "Cancel" and the scheduled backup successfully completed later. Recently, I have been unable to get any successful backups. I have searched barefruit.co.uk on the web and found nothing helpful. If I was running Windows, I would suspect malware of some sort. What is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't use `deja-dup`, but I did notice that `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.DejaDup` dumps interesting values. `man gsettings` will tell you how to change them.

Comment: @waltinator, thanks for the edit and response. I did the suggested dump and it was indeed interesting.  Computer names appeared several times in the listing, all different and none the current name. I edited the settings, but it didn't help. I removed deja-dup and all related directories and files and reinstalled the program. The problem persisted with the new installation. Finally, I did a new web search on unallocated.barefruit.co.uk. The site has caused enough trouble in the past month to produce a fair number of applicable search results. Based on these I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

unallocated.barefruit.co.uk is a redirect that provides internet advertising. An ISP, Verizon in my case, can set their DNS server to redirect to the barefruit site in case of an invalid request and the requester gets a targeted ad instead of an error message. I suspect that deja-dup may be requesting an invalid address and inappropriately handling the unexpected response. I will contact deja-dup about the possible bug and try a Verizon workaround to deal with my immediate problem.